# Ansible unarchive module - pattern matching for 'src' parameter

Tags: deployment, ansible, continuous-deployment

In **build** configuration, CI server builds a *Service* package, assigns it a specific *Version*, and then archives it into file: *Service-Version.tgz*.

In **deploy** configuration, the same CI server downloads such variably named package. This configuration would like to copy the archive, unpack it and deploy the service on some host.

Expressing that in Ansible code:

```
 - name: Unpack Service on remote host
   unarchive: src="{{ src_dir }}/Service-*.tgz" dest="{{ host_dest_dir }}"
```

Ideally: Ansible would try to match anything with filename within the pattern.

In reality, this does not work:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to find '(...)/deploy/Service-*.tgz' in expected paths."}
```

How to make Ansible accept variadic names for 'src'?

(I figured I could create a task registering the real name by grepping the directory, but perhaps this can be done *within* Ansible itself?)

Comment: Yes, you need to get file name with `find` task and use its result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted by the earlier comment on your question another way to do this (assuming Ansible 2+) is with the `find` module.  This would look something along the lines of:

```
- name: Find Service package
  find: paths="{{ src_dir }}" patterns="Service-*.tgz"
  register: find_result
- name: Unpack service on remote host
  unarchive: src="{{ item.path }}" dest="{{ host_dest_dir }}"
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Comment: Went with that - seems like the best option. I've also added a sanity check, to ensure only a single package is matched:

`- name: ensure only a single service package is available
  fail: msg="the number of packages matching the service name pattern 'Service-*.tgz' must be exactly equal 1"
  when: "{{ find_result.files | length }} != 1"`

Answer (score 1):

If your CI server knows the filename and is running ansible then you could set the version of the filename on the command line and then reference that within your task:

```
ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars "version=${VERSION_FROM_CI_SERVER}"
```

Comment: Seems reasonable within CI, however, such a package would be unusable outside CI. Since it resolves the question, I will accept it, if no better answers shows up.